# ‘We didn’t get ten points each.’

Tags: adverbs, each-every

I got ten points, but you didn’t get ten points.

In this case, can I use sentence ‘we didn’t get ten points each’?

Or does it mean both of us didn’t get ten points?

Comment: You could say "We didn't _both_ get ten points (though I did)."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's ambiguous. It says "It is not true that we each got ten points."
That would be true if neither of you got ten points, or if just one of you got ten points.

Comment: It would also be true if you got 5 points and the other got 15 points.  Or if we got 100 points each, or 100 and 873 respectively.  Or literally ANY amount of points except for the two people getting exactly 10 points each.